# About the $\lim R_n -> 0 $ in the taylor theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Okay We know that

$$if \ |f^{(n+1)}≤M|\ then;\\R_n ≤ M\frac{(x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

Now we say that the series converges if $\lim R_n -> 0$

But isn't $(n+1)!>(x-c)^{n+1}$ after $\exists N$ such that $n>N$. I mean shouldn't $\lim \frac{(x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=0$ as $n-> \infty$

Therefore $$0≤|R_n| ≤ |M\frac{(x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}|$$ $R_n -> 0$ by sandwich.

But how come some functions have remainder not going to zero?

Comment: What if there exists no $M$ for your initial statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple.  They are [not analytic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function), and as a consequence, the remainder does not go to zero.

The classic example is usually given by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}&;x\ne0\\0&;x=0\end{cases}$$

whereupon the Taylor expansion at $x=0$ might give you a good chuckle.  Similar examples of such cases may be found in the given link above.

Comment: Can we say that if $f \epsilon C^{\infty}$ on a compact set, $R_n -> 0 $ ?

Thus would being $f \epsilon C^{\infty}$ imply that f is analytic?


It probably wouldn't imply that. Wouldn't imply $R_n -> 0 $ and is the main reason for that is boundary of $f^(n+1)$ could increase fast?

Comment: @Xenidia the above example is $C^\infty$.  In the link, there is an even wilder example of a $C^\infty$ function that is nowhere analytic.  And I do not understand the last half of your comment.